# Using Self Join

Tags: sql, oracle, self, self-join

I have two tables (see below) Employees and Departments.  Under the employees table, I have columns:

```
SQL> describe employees



Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPLOYEEID                                NOT NULL NUMBER(9)
 FIRSTNAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 LASTNAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 CITY                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 STATE                                     NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 DEPTID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(9)
 MANAGERID                                          NUMBER(9)
```

From that I need to Write a sql statement that shows each employees firstname, lastname, and their manager's firstname and last name - I tried self join to no avail.  Please, help.  Thank you!  Note:  I am very very new to this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you want to show employees that don't have a manager. Here's the basic code to handle the self-join:

```
SELECT
    E1.EMPLOYEEID,
    E1.FIRSTNAME,
    E1.LASTNAME,
    E1.DEPTID,
    E2.EMPLOYEEID   AS 'MANAGER_ID'
    E2.FIRSTNAME    AS 'MANAGER_FIRSTNAME',
    E2.LASTNAME     AS 'MANAGER_LASTNAME'
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E1
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE AS E2 ON E1.EMPLOYEEID = E2.MANAGERID
```

EDIT: I had a typo in the original response, so thanks to Frederick for catching that I accidentally put "EMPLOYEEDID" the join predicate, now MANAGERID. The rest of the post still stands, though.

If you wanted to display the employees that don't have a manager as well, you would change the "inner" join to a "left outer" join.

I would recommend researching self-joins and some of the disadvantages to using them, and possibly putting the management of an employee-manager relationship into a different table. There also doesn't appear to be a field that "flags" a user as being a manager or not (I don't know if this is a requirement for your application or not), which might be useful to you as well -- to prevent users that aren't managers of some kind or other from "becoming" managers in your table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you mean to use `INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE AS E2 ON E1.MANAGERID = E2.EMPLOYEEID` to show their manager's details

Comment: Yes, totally meant to type that. Good catch. Feel like a total dweeb when that's what I meant to put in the first place..

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this query where i am applying `self join` or `inner join`

```
SELECT emp.FIRSTNAME as EMPF, emp.LASTNAME as EMPL,man.FIRSTNAME as MANF, man.LASTNAME as MANL 
FROM Employees as emp 
INNER JOIN Employees as man on man.EMPLOYEEID = emp.MANAGER_ID
```

in order to get managers for particular employee.

you can refer this **[tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/)** to get examples and consequences of using this join.